# how to maintain bluetooth device connection throughout the react native app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx

I'm new to react native,
I've created an app using react native, I'm working on a Bluetooth device that connects with the app and gives me data.. everything is working fine. but I want the device to stay connected through out the app. but not on a single page.. since I need the device to give me data on specific buttons clicked on different pages.

is there a way to do it

thank you so much.

I tried to connect on a single page it worked absolutely fine, but if navigated to a separate page the device connection is lost, and again have to connect to read data.

ive used react native ble-plx library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do this in root of your project that accessible to all over

create a new sperate file in root ./src

```
const subscription = manager.onStateChange((state) => {
      if (state === 'PoweredOn') {
          this.scanAndConnect();
          subscription.remove();
      }
  }, true);
  return () => subscription.remove();
}, [manager]);
```

import this file in main root container of app
like below

```
 <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <View>
          <AppRoot />
          <Bluetooth /> // connection file import 
        </View>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much ravin. Thanks for the simple explanation too